# Sumar filas según encabezado de tabla HTML

Tags: jquery, html5

Con el siguiente código estoy sumando los valores de cada fila en la última celda...

```css
.head, .number, .sub, .dom {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" style="padding: 50px;">
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Documento</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>
     <input class="head" value="Sab">
    </th>
    <th>
     <input class="head" value="Dom">
    </th>
    <th>
     <input class="head" value="Lun">
    </th>
    <th>
     <input class="head" value="Mar">
    </th>
    <th>
     <input class="head" value="Mier">
    </th>
    <th>
     <input class="head" value="jue">
    </th>
    <th>
     <input class="head" value="Vie">
    </th>
    <th>
     <input class="head" value="Sab">
    </th>
    <th>
     <input class="head" value="Dom">
    </th>
    <th>
     <input class="head" value="Lun">
    </th>
    <th> Suma Domingos </th>
    <th> Total </th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>1035656856</td>
    <td>Oscar</td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="10">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="20">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="15">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="10">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="12">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="15">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="18">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="20">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="12">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="10">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="dom">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="sub">
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1123548965</td>
    <td>Jhon</td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="20">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="20">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="20">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="18">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="12">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="10">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="12">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="12">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="15">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="18">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="dom">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="sub">
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1234567890</td>
    <td>Marcos</td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="8">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="6">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="12">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="16">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="20">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="15">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="10">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="10">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="20">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="number" value="18">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="dom">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input class="sub">
    </td>
   </tr>
      <script>
  $("table tbody tr").each(function() {
   var sub = 0;
   $(this).closest("tr").find(".number").each(function(){
    if(parseFloat($(this).val())) {
     sub += parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
   });
   $(this).closest("tr").find(".sub").val(sub);
  });
      </script>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cómo puedo sumar sólo los valores según el encabezado?

Por ejemplo: solo los valores de los domingos.

**Nota:** los días en los encabezados van a ser dinámicos en función del mes actual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre asignar clases a los valores dependiendo el día al que perteneces, y al final hacer lo mismo que hiciste para sacar el total pero con las clases del día específico que necesitas, así:

```js
$("table tbody tr").each(function() {
  var sub = 0;
  var dom = 0;
  $(this).find(".number").each(function(){
    if(parseFloat($(this).val())) {
      sub += parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
  });
  
  $(this).find(".Dom").each(function(){
    if(parseFloat($(this).val())) {
      dom += parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
  });
  
  $(this).closest("tr").find(".sub").val(sub);
  $(this).closest("tr").find(".total_Dom").val(dom);
});
```

```css
.head, .number, .sub, .total_Dom {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" style="padding: 50px;">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Documento</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>
                    <input class="head" value="Sab">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="head" value="Dom">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="head" value="Lun">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="head" value="Mar">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="head" value="Mier">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="head" value="jue">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="head" value="Vie">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="head" value="Sab">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="head" value="Dom">
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input class="head" value="Lun">
                </th>
                <th> Suma Domingos </th>
                <th> Total </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1035656856</td>
                <td>Oscar</td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Sab" value="10">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Dom" value="20">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Lun" value="15">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Mar" value="10">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Mier" value="12">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number jue" value="15">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Vie" value="18">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Sab" value="20">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Dom" value="12">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Lun" value="10">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="total_Dom">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="sub">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1123548965</td>
                <td>Jhon</td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Sab" value="20">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Dom" value="20">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Lun" value="20">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Mar" value="18">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Mier" value="12">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number jue" value="10">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Vie" value="12">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Sab" value="12">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Dom" value="15">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Lun" value="18">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="total_Dom">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="sub">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234567890</td>
                <td>Marcos</td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Sab" value="8">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Dom" value="6">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Lun" value="12">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Mar" value="16">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Mier" value="20">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number jue" value="15">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Vie" value="10">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Sab" value="10">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Dom" value="20">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="number Lun" value="18">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="total_Dom">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="sub">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sería perfecto... pero tendría que generar los `class` de manera dinámica, lo cual complica un poco el código pero lo voy a intentar. Gracias!

Comment: @YESIDDOTNET pero los tr los generas desde un ciclo no? si lo haces asi es fácil

Comment: Es correcto. Con tu sugerencia es suficiente para la prueba que estaba realizando, me dio pistas para avanzar... El proyecto real va un poquito mas allá. Voy a seguir intentando. Gracias por el apoyo!!!